# Less CSS string variable concatenation

Tags: css, string, less, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have a LESS variable in a file called "variable.less" that looks like:

```
@maxcdn-heroku-ssl: "https://heroku-mywebsite.netdna-ssl.com";
```

I'm trying to import that variable into a separate LESS file and use it as so:

```
@import "variables.less";
.guide {
    background-image:url(@maxcdn-heroku-ssl+/public/image/Logo.default/Logo@2x.png);
```

This gives me the following error:

> expected ')' got '+'

How to do this properly?

Comment: [Here](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) is an example of how to use less variables as css values. I do not think you are able to concatinate a variable to a string.

Comment: So you don't think its possible to do what I want above?